# How to send modified values to delete stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I'm using Entity Framework 6 database first. The CUD operations of all my entities are mapped to stored procedures in the `.edmx` file. My DELETEs are not real deletes - they actually set a `IsDeleted` column from 0 to 1, and then the entities are filtered by `IsDeleted = 0`, so EF doesn't pick them up in SELECTs.

It all works well, except for one issue. My entities have a `UpdateDate` / `UpdateBy` column, which I want to update with the values of the current user and time when deleting. So I set them before calling `.SaveChanges()`, but what is sent to the database is the original values, and not the ones I've set.

It's worth noting that in order to delete, I pull the entity from the database (where these fields have some default values) and mark it for deletion.

How do I make EF send the modified values to the DELETE stored procedure?

**EDIT**
You wanted some code, so here it is. It's so trivial I thought it's redundant.

```
public List<Audit> CreateAuditData(DbContext context)
{
    var entries = from e in context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                  where e.State != EntityState.Unchanged
                  select e;
    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        Audit audit = new Audit();
        audit.CreateBy = audit.UserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        audit.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;

        IModel model = entry.Entity as IModel;
        switch (entry.State)
        {
        ...
        case EntityState.Deleted:
                model.UpdateBy = audit.CreateBy;
                model.UpdateDate = audit.CreateDate;
        ...
        break
        }
}
```

When I return from this method, I immediately call `SaveChanges()` on the context.

`Audit` is some other entity which I also save with every change. `IModel` is an interface all my entities implement, which contains the `UpdateDate` and `UpdateBy` properties.

Comment: No code, no clear problem statement, no answer possible...

Comment: I don't think this can ever work, because EF expects a stored procedure with only a an Id as argument. You must handle the soft delete as a normal update.

Comment: @GertArnold, that's not accurate. You can send any field of your entity to the procedure, but what will get sent is the original value, and not any changes the user made. That's the source of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since EF only sends the original values to the delete stored procedure, I had to modify the `DbEntityEntry.OriginalValues` collection of the entity with the values I wanted to send to the procedure. mapping the appropriate properties to procedure parameters, I was able to get these values in the database.